# using output of a program as input in same program

Tags: c, algorithm, file, permutation

I am writing a program to generate all possible permutations of a given series of numbers and then generate all possible binary trees from that permutations so, what I thought is having a program which generates permutations and stores the result to a file and then write further code to read line by line (which has all permutations ) and generate binary trees out of them, so right now I have written half program which generates permutation and it stores the result in file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//function to print the array
void printarray(int arr[], int size)
{
        FILE *fp;
    int i,j;
        fp=fopen("result.txt","w");
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
          //  printf("%d\t",arr[i]);
          fprintf(fp,"%d\t",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    fclose(fp);
}

//function to swap the variables
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

//permutation function
void permutation(int *arr, int start, int end)
{
    if(start==end)
    {
        printarray(arr, end+1);
        return;
    }
    int i;
    for(i=start;i<=end;i++)
    {
        //swapping numbers
        swap((arr+i), (arr+start));
        //fixing one first digit
        //and calling permutation on
        //the rest of the digits
        permutation(arr, start+1, end);
        swap((arr+i), (arr+start));
    }
}

int main()
{
   //taking input to the array
    int size;
    printf("Enter the size of array\n");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    int i;
    int arr[size];
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    //calling permutation function
    permutation(arr, 0, size-1);
    return 0;
}
```

but the problem here in this program is that this program only stores one permutation and does not stores other permutations in result.txt file, how do I go on storing result this way. Also program does not ends a blank cursor blinking which gives a false impression of infinite while loop.
I had to press Ctrl+c to end the program how to get rid of this?

Comment: Please do not each time open the file, write a line, and then close it again. This is horribly inefficient, since it means for *every* permutation, you will need to make (approximately three) operating system calls. Open the file in the beginning, and pass a handler through the calls that then write to the file.

Comment: Calling people morons is a sure way to make sure nobody helps you. Please be civil. Downvote means someone didn’t see the question suitable, or good enough. There’s no need to take it so seriously. As for the program hanging you could first run it in a debugger and see what’s happening.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

your `fopen("result.txt","w");` truncates file each time opened.
use `fopen("result.txt","a");` instead

Comment: yes I tried that and the result is horrible  there is infinite loop kind of thing in the output file

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define N 10

void print(int *num, int n)
{
        FILE *fp;
        fp=fopen("result.txt","a");
    int i;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
//        printf("%d ", num[i]);
          fprintf(fp,"%d ",num[i]);
    fprintf(fp,"\n");
   fclose(fp);
}
int main()
{
    int num[N];
    int *ptr;
    int temp;
    int i, n, j;
    printf("\nHow many number you want to enter: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\nEnter a list of numbers to see all combinations:\n");
    for (i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &num[i]);
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            temp = num[i];
            num[i] = num[i+1];
            num[i+1] = temp;
            print(num, n);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```